# graph decomposition into simple cycles

Tags: graphs

Given a directed graph with number of nodes not exceeding 3*10^4. Each node has indegree ranging from 1 to 5 and outdegree from 1 to 5. We need to partition the graph into vertex-disjoint simple cycles. It is necessary to use all the nodes but it is not necessary to use all the edges.

Comment: Remove all edges: Single nodes are simple cycles.

Comment: What research have you done?  Have you searched Google Scholar?  Have you searched Stack Exchange?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research on your own before asking, and to show us in the question what you've found so far.  30 seconds of searching turns up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cycle_cover, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/8563/5038, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23121799/781723.  If I can find what seems like an answer in 30 seconds of searching using search terms from your question, in the future I encourage you to do more research before asking.